# SQL statement (Oracle) that selects rows from tbl NOT IN pattern (selected from joined tables)

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have two tables: `tblAPARTMENT` and `tblRESERVATION`. I want a list of all apartmentID's which are not in the reservation-table with those dates.

I have tried:

```
SELECT apartmentID, apartmentNAME   
FROM tblAPARTMENT 
NOT IN   
(SELECT apartmentID FROM tblRESERVATION   
WHERE tblRESERVATION.startDate > _a-date_   
AND tblRESERVATION.endDate < _a-date_
```

I know there is a better way to write this, I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Can you describe what you want the query to do?

Comment: I want a list of all apartmentID's wich are not in the reservation-table with those dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntactically correct way to write your query is:

```
SELECT a.apartmentID, a.apartmentNAME   
FROM tblAPARTMENT a
WHERE a.apartmentID NOT IN (SELECT a.apartmentID
                            FROM tblRESERVATION r  
                            WHERE r.startDate <= _a-date_ AND r.endDate >= _a-date_
                           );
```

This is a reasonable way, but it is generally safer to use `not exists` rather than `not in` (due to `NULL` handling):

```
SELECT a.apartmentID, a.apartmentNAME   
FROM tblAPARTMENT a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.apartmentID
                  FROM tblRESERVATION r  
                  WHERE r.startDate <= _a-date_ AND r.endDate >= _a-date_ and
                        r.apartmentid = a.apartmentid
                 );
```

Comment: @user3540851 . . . That is a rather vague comment.  You should explain what the problem is.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that the start and end dates are looking at the same variable.  There will never be an apartment where the end date comes before the start date, but that's what this subquery specifies.

Comment: @AndyDan . . . That would seem logical.  The original question didn't say that the attempted query didn't work (although it could not have worked given the syntax).  It just asked for a syntactically correct version.  That said, I'm changing the answer to switch the order of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

how about this..? it will query apartmentIDs which are outside your specified date (in your original post) boundary..

```
SELECT tr.apartmentID, ta.apartmentNAME
FROM tblRESERVATION tr JOIN tblAPARTMENT ta
ON tr.apartmentID =ta.apartmentID 
AND tr.startDate <= _a-date_   
AND tr.endDate >= _a-date_
```

UPDATE:

actually I don't really know what you want..
if above query doesn't give you the result you want, you might wanna change this:

```
AND tr.startDate <= _a-date_   
AND tr.endDate >= _a-date_
```

to:

```
AND (tr.startDate <= _a-date_   
OR tr.endDate >= _a-date_)
```